# ASP.NET MVC Render Section on a Controller by Controller Basis

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

This might not have an implemented answer but, I was searching for an easy way to render a section block on a controller basis. Obviously `_ViewStart` is not going to work because it won't know what view to render the section for, but to show you what I mean....

/Shared/_Layout.cshtml

```
...
@RenderSection("Streetcar", required: false)
...
```

/_ViewStart.cshtml

```
...
@{
    Layout = "./Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
...
```

/Test/_ViewStart.cshtml

```
...
@{
    // notice layout isn't being set because we still want the global _ViewStart layout
}

@section Streetcar {
    Named Desire
}
...
```

In a perfect world, I could render a section by default for everything single view in the `Test` folder this way and catch all the views generated by the `TestController` Since it cannot be done this way, does anyone know of a way of doing this cleanly?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand what you're asking by

> Render Section on a Controller by Controller Basis

My answer is predicated on the assumption you just want `Nested Master Pages`.

So you're right, `_ViewStart` is a master page switch, not a layout/master page itself. But you can nest master pages:

/Shared/_Layout.cshtml

```
@RenderBody()
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

/_ViewStart.cshtml

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

/Views/Shared/_TestLayout.cshtml

```
@{
    // References 'global' masterpage
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

// And override it as necessary
@section scripts {
    <script>
        console.log("Nested layout ran");
    </script>
}

@RenderBody()
```

/Test/_ViewStart.cshtml

```
@{
    // Set test folder to use test master layout
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_TestLayout.cshtml";
}
```